# C# Enums are always none

Tags: c#, enums, flags

In C#, i have the following enum. i want to be able to run my verification function an return the issues found via said enum, but it seems to always contain OK.

everything ive read on this says to use 0 for none, which, to me at least, seems logically equivalent to OK, as there are "none" problems.
but if i check "enum.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)" it will return true 100% of the time, no matter how many others are set. i feel like if it doesnt equal 0, it shouldnt say it does. this seems broken to me.

What is the proper way to deal with this?

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidationResult
{
    OK,
    NotOK,
    ReallyNotOk
}
```

```
void Main()
{
    var x = ValidationResult.OK;
    Console.Write(x.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)); // true
    
    
    var y = ValidationResult.NotOk;
    Console.Write(y.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)); // still true for some reason
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `Flags` attribute for this, and you shouldn't be checking `.HasFlag` to test the enum value in this scenario.

Comment: i need flags to return multiple though, dont i? maybe the item has both NotOK and ReallyNotOK

Comment: #1. OK -- is default value. Can you add 1st type, before OK, named NONE?

Comment: Well you haven't defined the enum in a way to support flags in the first place... and "not having any problems" isn't logically a flag that would be "set". (What would `ValidationResult.OK | ValidationResult.NotOK` mean in your view?) It's okay to have a zero value of OK, but using that with `HasFlag` is not appropriate. Note that `HasFlag` is behaving exactly as described: "If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true". And the underlying value of `ValidationResult.OK` *is* zero.

Comment: it auto fills the values as 0,1,2,4,etc, and you cant "Set" okay anyways, (0+0=0)

Comment: "it auto fills the values as 0,1,2,4" - what do you expect to do that? The C# compiler certainly won't. It will populate the values as 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @PetNoire: It doesn't, but you won't notice the difference until you reach 4 enum values.

Comment: It feels like basically you need to do a bit more research about what flags-based enums really represent, thinking about the numeric values underlying them, and what `HasFlag` is intended to do.

Comment: idk what to tell you there, it is filling 4. my full enum has about 15 and they all work exactly as expected except OK, which the answer below gets me through

Comment: you all comment on the flags but fail to say what the issue is. the reason for it is because there could be 4+ different issues that all need to be returned, the goal was to make 0 be the lack of any of them, hence OK

Answer (score 5):

`0` isn't a flag, it is the complete absence of flags.  If the flags represent different types of failures, then it may be appropriate to give the label `Ok` to `0`... but it still isn't a flag and cannot be tested with `HasFlag`.

```
Console.Write(y == ValidationResult.OK); // works correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73573521/2921691), you can fix this by adding desired values manually like:

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidationResult
{
    OK = 1,
    NotOK = 2,
    ReallyNotOk = 4
}
```

Update:

As Ben pointed out in his comment, the presented solution lacks the possibility to present EITHER "OK" OR a concrete failure state. Thus I would propose using a class hierarchy instead of an enumeration.

A simple example can be found in the microsoft docs:
[Use enumeration classes instead of enum types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types)

Comment: Sure, but this opens the door to self-inconsistent combinations like `OK | NotOK | ReallyNotOK`.  OP correctly observed that "Ok" means "no problems".

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's true, I completely agree. I guess OP is searching for something like either "OK" or any failure of the desired enumeration. In my opinion and to my current knowledge that's not manageable with flags only.

Comment: `Thus I would propose using a class hierarchy instead of an enumeration` -- this is another option. we don't know real requirements. may be "customer want something strange". anyway, your answer is good as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace EnumTest
{
    [Flags]
    public enum ValidationResult
    {
        None = 0,
        OK = 1,
        NotOK = 2,
        ReallyNotOk = 4
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValidationResult x = ValidationResult.OK;
            Console.Write(x.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)); // true

            ValidationResult y = ValidationResult.NotOK;
            Console.Write(y.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)); // Result False

            ValidationResult z = ValidationResult.NotOK | ValidationResult.ReallyNotOk;
            Console.Write(z.HasFlag(ValidationResult.OK)); // Result False
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like Markus's answer, this opens the door to self-inconsistent combinations like `OK | ReallyNotOK`

Comment: @BenVoigt this is your assumption, we don't know all requirements